# Merge Ranges from Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have few files with equal structure. I read cell from then and I need to concatenate them.

For example:

```
    using MOI = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    MOI.Range range1 = GetCellFormFile("file1");
    MOI.Range range2 = GetCellFormFile("file2");
    MOI.Range total = ???
```

Comment: How would you merge ranges from different files? What do you expect that would accomplish? Do you just want to sum the numbers from them?

Comment: @mason I don't need to merge data, only concatenate two ranges. The data has equal structure.

Comment: @mason rewrite question

Comment: What's some sample input and what's the expected sample output?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the cell values to strings and concatenate the strings.

```
string s1 = range1.Value2.ToString();
string s2 = range2.Value2.ToString();
string s3 = s1 + s2;
```